# How to build self-contained java fx application for various platform in a single build that runs on Window 8 64 bit machine

Tags: build, javafx, packaging, self-contained

> .Can be distributed as .zip or packaged as platform-specific installer.
>
> •No application changes, the same jar app binaries can be deployed as
> a native bundle, double-clickable jar

[Source](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx)

with reference to these two above point I would like to do the same. Can any body show me sample build.xml or help links to achieve these two points?

I am running my build on Window 8, 64 bit machine and that is successfully producing an 64 bit window executable to launch self-contained java fx application using following javafx task -

```
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
           nativeBundles="all"
           outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
    <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </fx:resources>
    <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
```

Now I need to produce various O.S. installer to launch their respective self-contained java fx application on MAC and Linux. I would like to produce O. S. wise installer in the same build that is running on window 8 64 bit machine. Is this possible?

I can compromise with installer, if this is not possible to build installer for MAC and Linux on Window platform but some how, can build a self-contained java fx application for various platform i.e. for MAC and Linux, in a single build that runs on Window 8 64 bit machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build native app bundles for Windows, Linux & Mac in a single build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036590/how-to-build-native-app-bundles-for-windows-linux-mac-in-a-single-build)