# How to build native app bundles for Windows, Linux & Mac in a single build?

Tags: deployment, ant, javafx-2, executable-jar

I am running my build on Windows 8 O.S. , 64 bit machine. I have JavaFx2.0 and Java 1.7.0_09 installed on my system. I am able to build a 64 bit window executable that launches my JavaFx application as a self-contained Javafx application.

Now I want to deliver native app bundles on Windows, Linux and Mac without build my project on all three platforms i.e I would like to achieve these set of bundles in a single build that I suppose to run on by Windows 8 O.S. 64 bit machine.

I am also okay if I can do it by distributing a single Application JAR file as .zip for MAC and Linux. But what I want is that JAR should work on there respective platform.

When I used to run a single application Jar on MAC using command

java -jar application.jar

It always shows a dialog "The application require a newer version of Java Run-time" with download link. Even I have downloaded and successfully installed it on my MAC machine but it still shows me the same window.

I don't want the users to experience such difficulties while running my JavaFX application on MAC and Linux.

What I need to ship more with the Application JAR so the users can run my JavaFx application on MAC and Linux without any hassle?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are making the JavaFX Solution in a 64bit machine and on the other hand you must be having all the SDK and runtime for 64bit version. The problem is that the application made using 64bit version of SKD would required 64 bit OS to render itself. So the bottom line is, is yout mac and linux PC have 64bit version of OS and JavaFX Runtime as well as Java7.X all 64 bit? If not then you must update your runtime to 64bit version or make your application in a 32bit version of SDK. One quick suggestion. If your mac or linux is 64bit(I dont have much idea about mac) then just install a browser i.e. 64bit version and runtimes and try out. I was having the same problem and that got fixed. Let me know if my answer caused any confusion.

Comment: +1. Thanks Shiva for quick response. Let me check and I will get back to you.

Comment: Yes. I have build JavaFX application jar on Windows 64 bit machine whereas my MAC and Linux are 32 bit version. I guess this does not matter while running application Jar using Java -jar application.jar

Comment: Whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit it will create the same JAR which will run on either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I was using 64bit Win7 OS with 64bit SDK and Runtime. It did not Run on Ubuntu32 bit  so I tested it on 64bit version with 64bit skd it worked. I guess this might be the issue. Even in 64Bit OS if you try running your App on a 32bit Browser it would Crash saying the same error. hope this helps :)

Comment: I was making a web app using JavaFX2.1 and running it on a 32bit Browser, it asked me to update the Runtime but when the same app was opened on a 64bit Browser it went fine!

Comment: Okay Shiva. Thanks for details. Let me build 32 bit application jar and check. I will get back to you. thanks. :)

Comment: Java installs separate VMs for 32bit and 64bit, and you will likely have both installations on a 64bit machine - those VM's versions may well differ. A 32bit browser on a 64bit OS will load the 32bit VM, and a 64bit browser the 64bit version, so an app may run in one and not the other.